# Folder filled with 10M+ log files and I can't delete them

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, out-of-memory

I had a logging process go haywire on one of my servers and I now have *tons* of files that I can't delete:

```
➜  logs  ls -l | wc -l
11135951
➜  logs  rm log*
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

Ideas?  I could just blow the server away but I'm genuinely curious about how to actually fix this.

Comment: Something like `find . -type f -name 'log*' -exec rm {} \;`? But be careful!

Comment: I reckon you should post this solution as an actual answer. Because it is the answer (or one of the possible answers), and if you post it as an actual answer, the question will show up in SO with an indicator that it does have an answer (and whether it was upvoted, or accepted, etc.) If you’re concerned about people downvoting it, please don’t be, because I will upvote it at least :)

Comment: I'm guessing that the rm has issues. Can you remove one? Can you remove in patterns of 10 or 100? That would confirm it. Then you can use xargs or write a bash script that removes on by one.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Meh, someone else already posted a somewhat better version. (I usually advocate `-delete` over `-exec rm`, not sure why it slipped my mind this time.)

Comment: @mark It's more likely Bash that's having problems expanding the glob.

Comment: @Biffen true, but ls does not have the issue. Or would there be a difference between the execution of ls and ls * ; ls: expands by itself and ls *: expansion by bash? Interesting

Comment: @Biffen I like your answer just fine too :) But anyway, the question did end up with the right answer being posted, so we’re all good.

Comment: @Biffen btw I’m surprised nobody’s ever asked this question on SO before, because it’s also a good question (and I now realize I didn’t take the time to upvote the question yet, so I just now did that too)

Comment: @mark `ls -l` doesn't have a glob  for Bash to expand. I bet `someothercommand *` will result in `-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory` too.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -name 'log*' -delete
```

Would be the most efficient way to do it

In most cases replacing -delete with-print would show you all the files which would be removed. In your case though I don't think that will help

@biffen points out that it will do sub dirs too

To prevent this use the maxdepth argument

-maxdepth 1

1 limits to current dir

Comment: This is different from `rm log*` in that it will apply to files in subdirectories as well. Just a caveat.

Comment: Added to the answer to prevent that